# having trouble using structs and filling their variables with functions (usingpointers)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct

Okay so I'm trying to do an art gallery management program (kind of), and when inserting the values into the struct the programm crashes. anyone can spot erros/bad coding?

Here is my code (sorry the variable names are in portuguese):
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "liga.h"

using namespace std;

bool menu1=false,
     menu2=false,
     menu3=false;

int opc,opc1;
string key="1qaz2wsx",pass;

int main()
{
    OBRAS database;
    OBRAS *ptr;

    ptr=&database;

    do {
        printf("\n\t********************     GESTOR ADAO     ********************\n");
        printf("\t\t   ->            modo admin          - prima 1\n");
        printf("\t\t   ->            modo guest          - prima 2\n");
        printf("\t\t   ->               exit             - prima 3\n");
        cin>>opc;

        if (opc<1 || opc>3)  printf("\nInseriu uma opcao invalida, tente de novo.\n\n");

        if (opc==1) {
            do {
                cin.sync();
                cin.clear();
                system("cls");
                printf("Insira a password:\n");
                cin>>pass;

                if (pass!=key) printf("\nPassword incorreta, tente de novo;\n");

            } while (key!=pass);

            do {
                cin.sync();
                cin.clear();
                system("CLS");
                printf("\n\t********************     GESTOR ADAO     ********************\n");
                printf("\t\t   ->            inserir obra          - prima 1\n");
                printf("\t\t   ->            listar obras          - prima 2\n");
                printf("\t\t   ->                voltar            - prima 3\n");
                cin>>opc1;

                if (opc1<1 || opc1>3)  printf("\nInseriu uma opcao invalida, tente de novo.\n\n");

                if (opc1==3)  menu2=true;

                if (opc==1) {
                    cin.sync();
                    cin.clear();
                    inserir(ptr);
                }
            } while(menu2==false);

        }

        /*else if (opc==2) ->MODO GUEST, sem pass, read only*/

        if (opc==3)  menu1=true;
    } while (menu1==false);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

liga.h

```
#ifndef LIGA
#define LIGA

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

typedef struct obras {
    char autor[50];
    char nome[50];
    int ano;
    int price;
}OBRAS;

#include "inserir.h"

//#include "main.cpp"
//AQUI SÃO CHAMADOS OS OUTROS HEADERS
/*#include "inserir.h"
#include "lista.h"*/

#endif
```

inserir.h

```
void inserir(OBRAS *ptr) {
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    system("CLS");
    printf("Insira o nome do autor da obra:\n");
    scanf("%[50]", ptr->autor);

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    printf("Insira o nome da obra:\n");
    scanf("%[50]",ptr->nome);

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    printf("Insira o ano em que foi feita a obra:\n");
    scanf("%d",ptr->ano);

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    printf("Insira o preco da obra:\n");
    scanf("%d",ptr->price);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char` arrays instead of `std::string`, and `printf` and `scanf` instead of `std::cout` and `std::cin`?  Your incorrect uses of `scanf` jump out as the first problem.

Comment: how can I use std::cin and still send the input using a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Like aschepler mentioned in his comment, change all `char`s to `std::string`s and all `scanf`s to `std::cin`s, like so:

```
typedef struct obras {
    std::string autor;
    std::string nome;
    int ano;
    int price;
}OBRAS;
```

and in your inserir.h:

```
void inserir(OBRAS *ptr) {
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    system("CLS");
    std::cout << "Insira o nome do autor da obra:\n";
    std::cin >> ptr->autor;

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << "Insira o nome da obra:\n";
    std::cin >> ptr->nome;

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << "Insira o ano em que foi feita a obra:\n";
    std::cin >> ptr->ano;

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << "Insira o preco da obra:\n";
    std::cin >> ptr->price;
}
```

While editing your post I saw (luckily) a commented line `#include "main.cpp"`. Don't do that, that's really bad practice.